# I have to login twice, to login?

Tags: php

my website has a login script, and for some reason you have to login, then it goes back to the login page and then you login again and its fine, it must be something to do with the login script, but not sure where...

```
    <?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $username=""; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name=""; // Database name
    $tbl_name="members"; // Table name

   // Connect to server and select databse.
   mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
   mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

   // username and password sent from form
   $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
   $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

   // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
   $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
   $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
   $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
   $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

   $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and    password='$mypassword'";
   $result=mysql_query($sql);

   // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
   $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
   // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row


   if($count){
        session_start();
       session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION['SESS_PASSWORD'] = $mypassword;
        session_write_close();
       header("location: login_success.php");
   }

   else 
  {
  include("loginhtml.html");
  } 
 ?>
```

then the checklogin, (which is at the top of each page)

```
          <?php
          session_start();
          if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']) || !isset($_SESSION['SESS_PASSWORD']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']) == '')) {
            //someone's not logged in
    header("location: index.php"); //it's suppose to actually be there
            exit();
          }
         ?>
```

any ideas??

cheers

Comment: What value do you get in `$count` when you first try to login? Can you add a `var_dump($count)` after you fetch num_rows and tell us the output after first login attempt?

Comment: how do I do this? I'm sorry but I'm not that ofey with PHP, just learning.

Comment: You don't need to store the password in the session. Just look for the username in session and it will work the same (only you have access to `$_SESSION`, so if the username is there is because you put it there, when the user entered the correct login information). Also, you should store the password encrypted in the database, using a hash algorithm like sha1 (and on top of that, use salting and stretching, but for now at least use sha1).

Answer (score 0):

you need to make it like this

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");



session_start();


if(isset($_POST))
{
    // username and password sent from form
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and    password='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row


    if($count){
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION['SESS_PASSWORD'] = $mypassword;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: login_success.php");
    }
    else
    {
        include("loginhtml.html");
    } 
}
```

Comment: that is now checklogin right? do I have to amend my first script as its now got the same in it??

Comment: so I just put that script as loginok, and leave the checklogin script as it is? thanks

Comment: you can put that code on top/below of your index.php - (depending on where you want to place the login form if the visitor is not logged in)

Comment: ok so I put this script in place of the first script, which is loginok, which is activated when loging in. this then activates checklogin (which is the 2nd script and on top of each page) but I still have to login again. is it something to do with loginsuccess?? its just html that redirects to the homepage...

Comment: follow this diagram

index.php
 -db connect
  if $_POST and ok
   --redirect to loginsuccess
  else
   --show loginerror
  
  -if no session
   show login form

Comment: its ok, its seems to work now, I just didn't have checklogin at the top of login_success so thats what was causing the loop! thanks

Comment: regarding the diagram, did you see my second answer on top? i show the right diagram there cause new lines are not working on this comment

Comment: sorry yes, thats the right paths, are you on about your amended script? thats what I'm using, do I seperate the script into two then? the first part is loginok, and the 2nd part (from session start) is the checklogin?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

follow this diagram

```
index.php
 -db connect

 -if $_POST and ok
   --redirect to loginsuccess
  else
   --show loginerror

 -if no session
   show login form
```

Comment: so I'm missing the no session part? how would I implement this?

Comment: -if no session, include the login form

Comment: thats what checklogin does isn't it?